# How can I extract distinct element from matrix's rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a matrix as shown and I want to extract from it an other matrix where without any duplicated element in each row.

This is the input matrix

```
head(Data_Achat2)
  ID_Achat   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
1     1349 433 405 451   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2     4890 405 405 416 416 388 464 416 388 392 405 393 405 433 453 392 416   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3     7881 405 384 390 395   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4     8081 442 405 405 475 464 405 442 405   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5     9465 457 417 416 391 441 441 392 441 401 441 432 388 395 466 464 399 475 466 464 481  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6    10626 432 390 433   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

In other word I want to get for example for the second row like this:

```
2     4890 405 416 388 464  388 392  393 433 453
```

Then, each row of the new matrix has only distincts element of the input one and all of results is in matrix (which include also 0 values for missing values).

Comment: You may need `apply` i.e. `apply(m1, 1, function(x) x[x!=0 & !duplicated(x)])`

Comment: Thanks, But I can't manipule it into matrix

Comment: @lmed You can keep it as a `list` as the number of elements are different for each row.  Or else, it can be padded with NAs and converted to matrix. i.e. `lst <- apply(m1, 1, function(x) x[x!=0 & !duplicated(x)]);do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, 'length<-', max(lengths(lst))))`

Comment: @akrun thanks! it works

Comment: hey @Imed, I noticed this played off the last Q you asked. I would recommend doing this step, before you manipulate the df. You should remove duplicates in your dataframe, and then do last step. It is immensly easier to do that than to do this step by transposing and applying a function across each column. The transposing of this df gets you back to where you started with it.

Comment: hey@MattW., I chose to work using list.But sadly I find then other difficult issue. In fact I want to attribute if there is a commun element in the tow list 1/4. In other word, I have tow list:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would row-wise apply a function that only retains the `m` unique values and then "pad" that vector to a length `N` with zeros, by adding `N - m` zeros to the unique values:

```
N <- ncol(Data_Achat2)

t(apply(Data_Achat2, 1, function(x){
  uniques <- unique(x)
  return(c(uniques, rep(0, N-length(uniques))))
}))
```

Which results in:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]    --- [,36] [,37] 
1  1349  433  405  451    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    ---     0     0 
2  4890  405  416  388  464  392  393  433  453     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    ---     0     0 
3  7881  405  384  390  395    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    ---     0     0 
4  8081  442  405  475  464    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    ---     0     0 
5  9465  457  417  416  391  441  392  401  432   388   395   466   464   399   475   481     0    ---     0     0 
6 10626  432  390  433    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    ---     0     0
```